# javascript html variable form entry

Tags: javascript

I have an html form select option dropdown with options: 
Transportation & Logistics Unit
TRANSFLO Solutions Business Unit
Western Business Unit
Other

I have the following javascript which enters values into Job Title variables based on the above selection.

```
var data = {
    "Transportation & Logistics Unit": [
        'Transportation &',
        'Logistics Unit'
    ],
    "TRANSFLO Solutions Business Unit": [
        'TRANSFLO Solutions',
        'Business Unit'
    ],
    "Western Business Unit": [
        'Western Business Unit',
        ''
    ],
    "Other": [
        document.getElementById('t1_t2_c_p_variableTextForm_pageTpl_v06CompanyDivision_other').value,
        ''
    ],
    "Western Canada Petroleum Solutions": [
        'Western Canada Petroleum Solutions',
        ''
    ]
}
```

The function is:

```
function SetJobTitle() {
    var choice = spec['v06CompanyDivision'].selectedText();
    spec['v02JobTitle1'].value = data[choice][0];
    spec['v03JobTitle2'].value = data[choice][1];
}
```

When the user selects "option" a text input box appears so text can be entered. The input box has an element id of "t1_t2_c_p_variableTextForm_pageTpl_v06CompanyDivision_other".

The above var data values for "Other" don't work, so I'm wondering if you can tell what I'm missing.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I am able to get something into spec['v02JobTitle1'].value by altering the SetJobTitle function like so:

```
function SetJobTitle() {
    var choice == spec['v06CompanyDivision'].selectedText();
    if (data[choice][0] = 'Other') {
        spec['v02JobTitle1'].value =       document.getElementById('t1_t2_c_p_variableTextForm_pageTpl_v06CompanyDivision_other').value;
    } else {
        spec['v02JobTitle1'].value = data[choice][0];
        spec['v03JobTitle2'].value = data[choice][1];
    }
}
```

However, it seems a little awkward since it's triggered by the changing dropdown. If I just edit the value in the input box it doesn't change. Is there something I can do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You should get value from your input box after selection or listen it changes and handle its

So your code

```
document.getElementById('t1_t2_c_p_variableTextForm_pageTpl_v06CompanyDivision_other').value
```

should be called each time as you change input box or any other event triggered and received value you should place in place you need

Comment: I do have this triggering that: spec['v06CompanyDivision'].onchange = SetJobTitle;

Answer (score 0):

Change `Other` entry  in `data` to `"Other": [function(){return document.getElementById('t1_t2_c_p_variableTextForm_pageTpl_v06CompanyDivision_other').value},'']`.

```
function SetJobTitle() {
    var choice = spec['v06CompanyDivision'].selectedText();
    if(choice === 'Other')
        spec['v02JobTitle1'].value = data[choice][0]();
    else
        spec['v02JobTitle1'].value = data[choice][0];
    spec['v03JobTitle2'].value = data[choice][1];
}
```

This should help you. Its a nasty code though.

Comment: The javascript is housed within an application environment which is producing the error, so I just get an error code number with no explanation.